# Object Comparison in .net

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

Is it any different from the CLR standpoint to implement `IEqualityComparer` vs overriding the `==` operator for the property you would use in the `IEqualityComparer<T>`? And if so, when would you use one against the other?

**Edit**

Ok it does make sense that the IEqaulityComparer used by the implementations of Hashtable - it slipped out of my mind when I was posting the question. So what about the extensions of Linq of IEnumerable. Does that mean that .net builds up a Hashtable when executing those kind of extension methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEqualityComparer` is not  `equal`, equal is for object (instance method) but EqualityComparer is for decoration for example in linq you want do specific distinct:

`personList.OrderBy(p=>p.ID).Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer())`

and

```
  class MyEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<Person>
  {

    public bool Equals(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
       if (p1.Age == p2.Age)
          return true;
       return false;
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Person p)
    {
        return p.Id.GetHashCode();
    }

  }
```

but equal is for Person:

```
public class Person
{
 public int ID{get;set;}
 public int Age{get;set;}
 public override bool Equals(object o)
 {
   //do stuff
 }
}
```

you can do any number of decoration by IEqualityComparer but you can't do this by instance method (you can write personList.Distinct(new AnotherComparer) ,...)

Comment: How is it used by a hashtable implementation , for example, in the linq Except() extension? Does that mean that compiler builds a Dictionary behind the curtains?

Comment: @Max: we shouldn't matter how the comparer is used in `Except` or `Distinct` etc., because that's an implementation detail. Anyway, internally it uses a class called `Set<T>` very similar to an `HashSet<T>`

Comment: @digEmALL, may be in this case - yes, but usually knowing what's inside helps you to use the interface better from the outside, no?

Comment: @Max, I can't understand `How is it used by a hashtable implementation` but about `Except` you can have your required implementation, I didn't know what compiler going to do behind (I think nothing specific). but for sure about it, it's better @Eric Lippert, or @Jon Skeet, answer to this question.

Comment: @Saeed: I don't get what you can't understand. In `Except()`, `Distinct()` or in `HashSet<T>` the custom comparer is used in the same way: two objects are compared by the hashcodes computed calling `comparer.GetHashCode(obj)`, if they're different, objects are considered different, if they're equal, objects are furtherly compare using `comparer.Equals(obj1,obj2)`. The same happens in case you don't give a custom comparer: simply, instead of `comparer.GetHashCode()` and `comparer.Equals()`, the `object.GetHashCode()` and `object.Equals()` are used.

Comment: @Max: yes, of course knowing what's inside helps a lot, but "theoretically" you should rely on the documentation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx) is used by the [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx), [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) and [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) classes in order to support a custom definition of "equality" for your types. That's why it provides [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.gethashcode.aspx), which doesn't have much to do with equality *per se*.

If you don't provide an `IEqualityComparer`, the classes mentioned above will default to [Object.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx), which implements *reference equality*. An overloaded `operator ==` won't be called in that context.

**EDIT:** Some LINQ's extension methods indeed take an `IEqualityComparer` as an argument, but the principle remains the same: if that argument is not specified, the method will end up comparing references, not values, and `operator ==` won't be called.

Comment: Actually, he meant `IEqualityComparer<T>` he just didn't format the code and the `<T>` part was hidden :-)

Comment: @digEmAll, nice catch :) Fortunately, the generic version of `IEqualityComparer` serves the same purpose as its non-generic counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

`IEqualityComparer` is used for example for comparison in `Dictionary<TK,TV>`.

It is completely different from overriding `==` operator because actually `Dictionary` (and in general whatever use `IEqualityComparer`) doesn't make any call to `==` operator.

At most, you can compare "implementing `IEqualityComparer` " vs "overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods", because indeed they're two ways to get the same thing (and I would say they're equal to me).