# Should an override of Equals on a reference type always mean value equality?

Tags: c#, .net

Without doing anything special for a reference type, `Equals()` would mean reference equality (i.e. same object).  If I choose to override `Equals()` for a reference type, should it always mean that the values of the two objects are equivalent?

Consider this mutable `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    readonly int Id;

    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Two objects that represent the exact same person will always have the same `Id`, but the other fields  might be different over time (i.e. before/after an address change).

For this object Equals could be defined to mean different things:

- Value Equality: all fields are equal (two objects representing the same person but with different addresses would return false)
- Identity Equality: the `Ids` are equal (two objects representing the same person but with different addresses would return true)
- Reference Equality: i.e. don't implement Equals.

**Question:** Which (if any) of these is preferable for this class? (Or perhaps the question should be, "how would most clients of this class expect Equals() to behave?")

**Notes:**

- Using Value Equality makes it more difficult to use this class in a `Hashset` or `Dictionary`
- Using Identity Equality makes the relationship between Equals and the `=` operator strange (i.e. after a check of two Person objects (p1 and p2) returns true for `Equals()`, you might still want to update your reference to point to the "newer" Person object since it is not value equivalent).  For example, the following code reads strange--seems like it does nothing, but it is actually removing p1 and adding p2:

  ```
  HashSet<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
  people.Add(p1);
  // ... p2 is an new object that has the same Id as p1 but different Address
  people.Remove(p2);
  people.Add(p2);
  ```

**Related Questions:**

- [Why does Microsoft recommend skip implementing equality operator for reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076143/why-does-microsoft-recommend-skip-implementing-equality-operator-for-reference-t)
- [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals#814889)
- [When Should a .NET Class Override Equals()? When Should it Not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709088/when-should-a-net-class-override-equals-when-should-it-not)
- [Simplify Overriding Equals(), GetHashCode() in C# for Better Maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707918/simplify-overriding-equals-gethashcode-in-c-sharp-for-better-maintainabilit)

Comment: In the case of multiple meanings of equality then why not provide some implementations of [`IEqualityComparer(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and let the consumer choose which equality to use?

Comment: @Romoku, seems reasonable, and then I would assume that means you would not implement `.Equals()` at all?

Comment: I think Marc Gravell's answer addresses that.

Comment: If two objects that represent the exact same person will always have the same `Id`, then I would expect `Equals` to compare only the `Id` fields. Anything else wouldn't make sense for the `Equals` method, and would be potentially dangerous if you're comparing mutable fields.

Comment: @JimMischel,  "Anything else wouldn't make sense for the Equals", why not?  I've given 3 meanings of what `Equals` could mean (and each of those meanings could be useful for a client).

Comment: I think it wouldn't make sense for an object's `Equals` method. It *would* make sense in some situations, and for those you would supply a custom equality comparer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, deciding the right rules for this is tricky. There is no single "right" answer here, and it will depend a lot on both context and preference Personally, I rarely bother thinking about it much, just defaulting to reference equality on most regular POCO classes:

- the number of cases when you use something like `Person` as a dictionary-key / in a hash-set is minimal

  - and when you do, you can provide a custom comparer that follows the *actual* rules you want it to follow
  - but most of the time, I'd use simply the `int Id` as the key in a dictionary (etc) *anyway*
- using reference equality means that `x==y` gives the same result whether `x`/`y` are `Person` or `object`, or indeed `T` in a generic method
- as long as `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are compatible, most things will just about work out, and one easy way to do that is to *not override them*

Note, however, that I would always advise the opposite for value-types, i.e. **explicitly** override `Equals` / `GetHashCode`; but then, writing a `struct` is ***really*** uncommon

Answer (score 6):

You could provide multiple [`IEqualityComparer(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) implementations and let the consumer decide.

Example:

```
// Leave the class Equals as reference equality
class Person
{
    readonly int Id;

    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class PersonIdentityEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        if(p1 == null || p2 == null) return false;

        return p1.Id == p2.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person p)
    {
        return p.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class PersonValueEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        if(p1 == null || p2 == null) return false;

        return p1.Id == p2.Id &&
               p1.FirstName == p2.FirstName; // etc
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person p)
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + p.Id.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + p.FirstName.GetHashCode();
        // etc

        return hash;
    }
}
```

See also: [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Usage:

```
var personIdentityComparer = new PersonIdentityEqualityComparer();
var personValueComparer = new PersonValueEqualityComparer();

var joseph = new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Joseph" }

var persons = new List<Person>
{
   new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Joe" },
   new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Mary" },
   joseph
};

var personsIdentity = new HashSet<Person>(persons, personIdentityComparer);
var personsValue = new HashSet<Person>(persons, personValueComparer);

var containsJoseph = personsIdentity.Contains(joseph);
Console.WriteLine(containsJoseph); // false;

containsJoseph = personsValue.Contains(joseph);
Console.WriteLine(containsJoseph); // true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, if class-type fields (or variables, array slots, etc.) `X` and `Y` each hold a reference to a class object, there are two logical questions that `(Object)X.Equals(Y)` can answer:

1. If the reference in `Y` were copied to `X` (meaning the reference is copied), would the class have any reason to expect such a change to affect program semantics in any way (e.g. by affecting the present *or future* behavior of any members of `X` or `Y`)

   If *all* references to the target of `X` were instantaneously magically made to point to the target of `Y`, *and vice versa*`, should the class expect such a change to alter program behavior (e.g. by altering behavior of any member *other than an identity-based `GetHashCode`*, or by causing a storage location to refer to an object of incompatible type).

Note that if `X` and `Y` refer to objects of different types, neither function may legitimately return true unless both classes know that there cannot be any storage locations holding a reference to one which could not also hold a reference to the other [e.g. because both types are private classes derived from a common base, and neither is ever stored in any storage location (other than `this`) whose type can't hold references to both].

The default `Object.Equals` method answers the first question; `ValueType.Equals` answers the second.  The first question is generally the appropriate one to ask of object instances whose observable state may be mutated; the second is appropriate to ask of object *instances* whose observable state will not be mutated *even if their types would allow it*.  If `X` and `Y` each hold a reference to a distinct `int[1]`, and both arrays hold 23 in their first element, the first equality relation should define them as distinct [copying `X` to `Y` would alter the behavior of `X[0]` if `Y[0]` were modified], but the second should regard them as equivalent (swapping all references to the targets of `X` and `Y` wouldn't affect anything).  Note that if the arrays held different values, the second test should regard the arrays as distinct, since swapping the objects would mean `X[0]` would now report the value that `Y[0]` used to report).

There's a pretty strong convention that mutable types (other than `System.ValueType` and its descendants) should override `Object.Equals` to implement the first type of equivalence relation; since it's impossible for `System.ValueType` or its descendants to implement the first relation, they generally implement the second.  Unfortunately, there's no standard convention by which objects which override `Object.Equals()` for the first kind of relation should expose a method which tests for the second, even though an equivalence relation could be defined which allowed comparison between any two objects of any arbitrary type.  The second relation would be useful in the standard pattern wherein an immutable class `Imm` holds a private reference to a mutable type `Mut` but doesn't expose that object to any code that could actually mutate it [making the *instance* immutable].  In such a case, there's no way for class `Mut` to know that an instance will never be written, but it would be helpful to have a standard means by which two instances of `Imm` could ask the `Mut`s to which they hold references whether they would be equivalent *if the holders of the references never mutated them*.  Note that the equivalence relation defined above makes no reference to mutation, nor to any particular means which `Imm` must use to ensure that an instance won't be mutated, but its meaning is well-defined in any case.  The object which holds a reference to `Mut` should know whether that reference encapsulates identity, mutable state, or immutable state, and should thus be able to implement its own equality relation suitably.