# What does it means when comparing an item tag of a class type with another variable of the same class type?

Tags: c#

So , I can't understand this:

- Let's say I have a class called : Bob and a variable called name with the type Bob.

And I do something like this:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if((Bob)item.Tag == name)
       { //code }

}
```

What this actually does? it compares the item with the type of the class if all the objects from the constructor are the same with the variable of that class?

Thanks

Comment: No, it checks if the objectreferences are the same. Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512444/object-comparison-in-net

Comment: @rene - How do you get that? Assuming these are reference types, then I'd expect `item == name` to do. Why the cast and call to `Tag`?

Comment: @Oded I expect a declaration of Bob name = new Bob(); because that is what the OP said. If name is a string then my statement doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create ListViewItems to add to a ListView, you have the option of setting its "Tag" property. It is of type Object and can handle any object. If you have the listViewItem displaying some customer details on screen, you may have the Tag property of the listViewItem set to the actual customer object in the business model.

Thus, you can grab "SelectedItem" off of the listView, cast it to "customer" class and act on it. This means you don't have to parse the text or anything to find the selected customer from the selected listViewItem.

Your code considers a ListView and a Bob in the "name" variable. The code enters the body of the if-statement for all listViewItems whose "Tag" property is the same (by reference) as the Bob instance in "name" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Microsoft summary on operator precidence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

The `.` (member selection) operator has higher precidence than the cast operator `(type)`.

Therefore, it takes `item.Tag` and tries to cast it to type `Bob`, then compares it for equality with `name`.

Comment: There is no triple equals in C#.

Comment: Too darn much JavaScript lately.  I will fix :-)  Thank you.

Comment: I never said the the name is a string. name is type of Bob ( class )

Comment: @JoshuaBlack Sorry, you are right...   you did say `name` is a `Bob`.  However, unless that cast doesn't throw an exception, that will never matter.

Comment: The tag is actually a reference of the text added to it?

Comment: I just checked the `ListViewItem` API, `Tag` is whatever object is associated.  I am inferring from your context that `Tag` is a `Bob`.

Comment: But what it actually compares if both are type of the same class ?